# How to set order for elements of json request body in swift?

Tags: json, swift

I need to set order for json, it sends request in alphabetic order, not what I want. Originally it is an xml request, converted to json. Because of alphabetic order, my header and other fields which should be on the top, comes down and I am getting error in my response.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Please read [this post on how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Edited, please check

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include relevant code (as text, no pictures). Clearly indicate what isn't working as desired. Clearly show current and desired output.